# Compare two PHP arrays after ORACLE database query

Tags: php, arrays, oracle

Dears,

I have a huge problem, from my perspective - please find details below:

I am querying two ORACLE databases and trying to compare results to get common rows between them basing on one column. It looks like this:

Firstly, I am searching for relevant codes, means Array1:

```
$query = "select e_code_nr from ERROR_nrs where ERROR_is_rel in ('1','2');

              $stmt = oci_parse($dbconnection_errtype, $query);
              oci_execute($stmt);
              $t=0;
              while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_NUM)) != false) 
              {
                  $array_errtype[$t] = $row[0];
                  $t++;
              }
```

As a result I receive array like:

```
Array ( 
[0] => C244 
[1] => C245
[2] => C248
[3] => C249
[4] => C250
[5] => C256
[6] => C257
[7] => C259
[8] => C260
[9] => C271
[10] => C281
)
```

I have a problem with a Array2, where there is many more columns.
I managed to query the second database (just in SQL Developer) with:

```
$query = "select * from pck_dst;
```

and as result I receive:

[SecondQueryResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5PFO.jpg)

I have a problem with:

1. I don't know how to query second database store such query results in PHP array;
2. I need help with comparing these two arrays basing on "if there is a row in Array2 in 4th column matching some of the rows from Array1 place full row from Array2 to Array3";
3. Display Array3 in HTML table.

I know I am asking much, but please - I have already wasted my full day for this.

Regards!

Comment: Are the databases accessible to each other though Linked servers? (with a user who has permissions?)
 If so you could execute 1 query and get all the needed data back at once.

Comment: Hello ;) The data is stored in two independent servers, databases, tables. 
There is no possibility to use just SQL to gather such info ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Assuming the servers can talk to each other, and you have the necessary privileges, you can create a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF01205):

```
create database link <link name>
connect to <user> identified by <password>
using <connection string>
```

Once this is done you can simply query against the two tables directly for exactly the resultset you need:

```
$query = "select
            t1.*
          from
            pck_dst@<link name> t1,
            ERROR_nrs t2
          where
            t1.e_code_nr = t2.e_code_nr
            and ERROR_is_rel in ('1','2')";
$stmt = ...
```

**Method 2:**

If you can't use the first method then you could use the resultset from the first query as parameters to the second:

```
$db2 = oci_connect($username, $password, $connection_string);
$query = "select * from pck_dst where e_code_nr in ('" . implode("','", $array_errtype) . "')";
$stmt = oci_parse($db2, $query);
...
```

***NOTE:*** This assumes `$array_errtype` contains clean, trusted data! For defence in depth you should always use [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php).

Comment: Method 2 helped ;) Thanks mate! Cheers!